# How to get only the list of the available products sizes?

Tags: mysql

Ive two tables **Sizes_description** (clothes sizes) and **stock** quantity. I want to know which sizes are in stock.
If I try the following query I get also sizes that are not in stock.

---

```
| SIZES_DESCRIPTION   |
-----------------------
id  size1 size2 size3 
-----------------------
1      M      L     X  
2     40     42    43  
-----------------------

-----------------------------
| STOCK                     |
-----------------------------
id  sizeId qty1 qty2 qty3
-----------------------------
1     2       0    5    0
2     1      42   43    0
-----------------------------
```

if I try the following I get also sizes not in stock

```
select s.size1,s.size2,s.size3 from SIZES_DESCRIPTION as s, stock as stock WHERE s.id=stock.sizeId AND (stock.qty1>0 OR stock.qty2>0 OR qty3>0)
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.  this is not a 'do it for me' site - you should ideally post what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: thanks Randy. Im still puzzled on that query that's why i did not post any query on that. the problem is that I should SELECT sizes_tab field n1 or n2 or n3 only if there some stock of articles that use that id from size tables, and in a DISTICT manner in the case there are more articles with same sizeid

Comment: select s.n1,s.n2,s.n3 from sizes_tab as s, articles as a, stock as sto WHERE a.sizeid=s.id AND s.id=sto.id AND (sto.n1>0 OR sto.n2>0 OR sto.n3>0)

Comment: Could you explain (expected) relations between your tables?

Comment: articles have a relation with sizes_tab trought articles.sizeid=sizes_tab.id. Stock is related to articles trought stock.articleid=articles.id

Comment: If it is your database, please consider normalizing it further. The columns ``n1``, ``n2`` and ``n3`` in both ``sizes_tab`` and ``Stock`` are very likely to cause problems further down the line.

Comment: I've updated the main post and changed to stock fields name. in the real db those fields have different names.

Comment: can i write again the whole question?

Comment: @logicos Yes you can edit your question

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sd.size1
From sizes_description sd
INNER JOIN Stock s On
sd.id = s.sizeId
Where s.qty1 > 0

UNION ALL

Select sd.size2
From sizes_description sd
INNER JOIN Stock s On
sd.id = s.sizeId
Where s.qty2 > 0

UNION ALL

Select sd.size3
From sizes_description sd
INNER JOIN Stock s On
sd.id = s.sizeId
Where s.qty3 > 0
```

Comment: @logicos I didn't have a chance to test this query but I will do so a bit later on

Comment: Evan ive read you are skilled with js and jQuery. is there a way I can contact you privately? if u can drop me a line galaga987 AT hotmail DOT com